# Why is my partial home directory backup is bigger than my full backup?

Tags: cpanel, backups

I just made two backups with cPanel. Both has `.tar.gz` extensions. One is home directory backup that is 134,2 MB. And the other is a full backup that is 67,4 MB.

What causes the difference? Is it normal or is there a problem here?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the partial backup is compressing something that the full backup is not, to address the issue you need to find out the difference between both files.

It's likely the partial backup is actually compressing the the full backup `tar.gz` and all the other files because `2x67mb = 134mb`. To find out the contents of your compressed files simply download them to your desktop and then view them with something like [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm), if you prefer to do everything via the terminal then by running the below command it will actually tell you the difference between each of files:

`diff <(tar -tvf partial-backup.tar.gz | sort) <(tar -tvf full-backup.tar.gz | sort)`

Answer (score 3):

It's because when you request a Full Backup, your "Full Backup archive" gets saved into your home directory. So when you then download the "Home Directory" it downloads the home directory including the Full Backup archive which is now saved within it.